# ExecuteSqlCommand parallel execution

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, parallel.foreach

SQL Server 11.0.3, C# .NET 4.5, WCF, EF v4.0.30319

I have the following table that store queries :

```
OBJECT_TYPE     OBJECT_NAME         OBJECT_TYPE_NAME    OBJECT_QUERY
1               HUB_PERSON          HUB                 MERGE INTO ...
1               HUB_GPS             HUB                 MERGE INTO ...
2               LNK_PERSON_GPS      LNK                 MERGE INTO ...
2               SAT_CURR_PERSON     SAT                 MERGE INTO ...
2               SAT_GPS             SAT                 MERGE INTO ...
2               SAT_HIST_PERSON     SAT                 MERGE INTO ...
```

I have to execute queries from my service in the order specified by the `OBJECT_TYPE` column. Queries that have the same `OBJECT_TYPE` can be executed in any order, it is why I want to parallelize execution of these queries if possible.

Here is the function I am currently using, without parallelism :

```
public int ExecuteLoadSources()
        {
            int nb = 0;
            using (POCDVEntities POCDb = new POCDVEntities())
            {
                using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
                {
                    IEnumerable<string> res = (
                        from a in POCDb.LOADING_SOURCE_QUERY
                        orderby a.OBJECT_TYPE
                        select a.OBJECT_SQLSRV_QUERY
                    );
                    foreach (string req in res)
                    {
                        POCDb.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(req);
                    }
                    nb = POCDb.SaveChanges();
                    transaction.Complete();
                }
            }
            return nb;
        }
```

I tried `Parallel.ForEach` like this :

```
public int ExecuteLoadSources()
        {
            int nb = 0;
            using (POCDVEntities POCDb = new POCDVEntities())
            {
                using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
                {
                    IEnumerable<string> res = (
                        from a in POCDb.LOADING_SOURCE_QUERY
                        select a.OBJECT_SQLSRV_QUERY
                    );
                    int maxValue = (from a in POCDb.LOADING_SOURCE_QUERY select a.OBJECT_TYPE).Max();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= maxValue; i++)
                    {
                        IEnumerable<string> res2 = (
                            from a in POCDb.LOADING_SOURCE_QUERY
                            where a.OBJECT_TYPE == i
                            select a.OBJECT_SQLSRV_QUERY
                        ).ToList();
                        Parallel.ForEach(res2, req2 =>
                        {
                            POCDb.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(req2);
                        });
                    }
                    nb = POCDb.SaveChanges();
                    transaction.Complete();
                }
            }
            return nb;
        }
```

The first time I run the function, I get `The underlying provider failed on Open.`, then I try again an get `Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.`

Am I doing it right?
Any suggestions?

Comment: Well for one I don't think one `SqlConnection` can be used from multiple threads concurrently, even with MARS. And that `Parallel.ForEach` will put `ExecuteSqlCommand` onto a different thread which might make that `TransactionScope` useless.

Comment: OK, so I can just assume it is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I can kind of give an abstract answer to this, it probably won't directly answer your question (and i don't have the rep to post a comment instead) but it is still valuable information for this type of problem.

There are a few issues with what you are trying to do.

The first is database contexts (and by extension sql connections) and thread concurrency. You absolutely cannot share a connection across threads, you must create a new connection on each thread as it spawns in parallel. This is actually not a bug deal because of connection pooling, so your performance hit is minimal anyways. So in your case, you would need to create the context instance inside the concurrency block.

The second is that performing parallel queries on a database inside of a transaction is generally not a good strategy. The reason for this is that when you run multiple simultaneous queries on the same database you need to be mindful of your isolation mode. Depending on connection and global settings, you would likely be hammering your log/journal and invoking the DTC. If your entire set of queries must be transactionally safe as a whole then you will not benefit at all by running the queries in parallel and should instead run each query sequentially. If only each individual query must be transactionally safe, then you should create the transaction context within the concurrency block.

The last is just a suggestion to use `Task` instead of `Parallel`. having a nested structure of tasks that can be run in parallel makes a bit more organizational sense than executing parallel concurrency blocks in a loop. In this case you would have a master task (which you could `Wait()` on) that would have child tasks for each `OBJECT_TYPE`. You could produce your `Task` structure by iterating a `GroupBy` query on your query data set. Like is said earlier though, this is just a suggestion and not really necessary to accomplish parallel execution of queries.

Something else to consider too (similar to the `Task` strategy), is to use async methods to execute each query and then a simple function to invoke each async method and await all at the end. Just a thought.